# Difference between jagged and rectangular arrays

Tags: java, arrays

So i realize that the main difference is one can hold different size rows or columns while the other has equal size for all. Are there other differences?
Additionally, how would i go about implement each on code?

If this question has already been asked , please don't hesitate to close this  and link me to the question.

Comment: Is there any particular use you need this for?

Comment: I guess i'm just trying to get a better understanding since they seemed similar in code syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[][] rectangular = new int[10][10];
int[][] jagged = new int[10][];
for(int i = 0;i < 10; i++)
    jagged[i] = new int[i+1];
```

First one creates a 10x10 rectangular array, the second one creates a jagged array, with the 2nd dimension going from 1 to 9 elements.

There are no *significant* differences, but Java supports jagged arrays unlike some other languages.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what languages don't support jagged arrays?

Comment: Probably not many, since that'd be a very limiting feature and is kind of a strange thing to do

Comment: Well, `C` doesn't have "true" jagged arrays, requiring pointers to get the same effect.

Comment: I know C# has built in rectangular arrays in the form of `new int[n, m]`, but I think that is just syntactical sugar in front of `new int[n*m]`

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you're using it for. If you're trying to implement a 2D grid like a chessboard, you'd want a rectangular array. If you're trying to implement a file-like system with an array for each line, each line being an array of words, then it would be jagged.

Rectangular Chessboard:

```
int[][] chessboard = new int[8][8];
```

Jagged File Representation (with 10 lines):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file"));
String[][] file = new String[10][];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    file[i] = reader.readLine().split();
```

Comment: A downvote without explanation, what a great way to improve